# Boolean Logic not working in Joomla 4 Smart Search when wrapping two words within quotation marks

Tags: joomla-4.x, smartsearch

I am having a problem with my site at https://www.shalomadventure.com where the Smart Search is not respecting the Boolean login. If I wrap two words within parentheses and do a search we are getting results that are not an exact match of the two words. What is not working is the following:

Entering `"this and that"` (with quotes) into the search form will return results containing the exact phrase `this and that`.

At the search page, I am entering the term `"Ten Commandments"` and am expecting to ONLY receive results that have that exact phrase, but instead I am also getting results that contain partial results.

For example one of the results had the lone word `Commandments` without the word `Ten`.

Another of the result has the word `Listen` with the highlight on the letters `ten`.

Is there anything that be done to fix this?

PS. I submitted this a few days ago at forum.joomla.org and it is gettng viewed a lot, but nobody is responding: https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=808&t=1000516